# I have error HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: javascript, java, geotools

I make a Web map system use openlayers, geoserver. I want to modify shapefile with geotools. So I make a jsp file to modify dbf file and textfile(text file is database).But I have an error.
It is jsp complie error unable to compile class for JSP

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 61 in the jsp file: /filesave2.jsp
DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry cannot be resolved to a type
58:         String progress = request.getParameter("怨듭젙瑜�");
59:         String gujork = request.getParameter("援ъ“�벑湲�");
60:         String area = request.getParameter("�뿰硫댁쟻");
61:         DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry dbf = new DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry();
62:         dbf.dbfmodify(�엯�젰二쇱냼,num ,sgg, period, youngdo, progress, gujork, area);
63:         Filemove fm = new Filemove();
64:         fm.filemove();


An error occurred at line: 61 in the jsp file: /filesave2.jsp
DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry cannot be resolved to a type
58:         String progress = request.getParameter("怨듭젙瑜�");
59:         String gujork = request.getParameter("援ъ“�벑湲�");
60:         String area = request.getParameter("�뿰硫댁쟻");
61:         DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry dbf = new DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry();
62:         dbf.dbfmodify(�엯�젰二쇱냼,num ,sgg, period, youngdo, progress, gujork, area);
63:         Filemove fm = new Filemove();
64:         fm.filemove();


An error occurred at line: 63 in the jsp file: /filesave2.jsp
Filemove cannot be resolved to a type
60:         String area = request.getParameter("�뿰硫댁쟻");
61:         DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry dbf = new DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry();
62:         dbf.dbfmodify(�엯�젰二쇱냼,num ,sgg, period, youngdo, progress, gujork, area);
63:         Filemove fm = new Filemove();
64:         fm.filemove();
65: %>
66: 


An error occurred at line: 63 in the jsp file: /filesave2.jsp
Filemove cannot be resolved to a type
60:         String area = request.getParameter("�뿰硫댁쟻");
61:         DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry dbf = new DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry();
62:         dbf.dbfmodify(�엯�젰二쇱냼,num ,sgg, period, youngdo, progress, gujork, area);
63:         Filemove fm = new Filemove();
64:         fm.filemove();
65: %>
66: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

And it is my code(jsp file)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="org.geotools.*" %>
<%@page import="good.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<%
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
        response.setDateHeader("Expires",0);
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String data = request.getParameter("nameText");
        String filePath = "C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/LTNB/dbdb.txt"; //파일을 생성할 전체경로
        String ifcnt = "";
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String M = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"_"+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"_"+c.get(Calendar.DATE)+"_"+c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+"_"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+"_"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        if(data == ""){
            ifcnt = "1";
        } else {
            try{
                File file = new File("C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/LTNB/dbdb.txt");
                File file2 = new File("C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/LTNB/"+M+".txt");
                file.renameTo(file2);

                File f = new File(filePath); // 파일객체생성
                f.createNewFile(); //파일생성

                // 파일쓰기
                BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath), "UTF-8")); //파일쓰기객체생성
                String[] data2 = data.split("★");

                for(int i=0; i<data2.length; i++)
                {
                    if(i==(data2.length-1)){
                        output.write(data2[i]);
                    } else {
                        output.write(data2[i] + "\n"); //파일에다 작성
                    }
                }

                output.close(); //파일핸들 닫기

                } catch (IOException e) { 
                    System.out.println(e.toString()); //에러 발생시 메시지 출력
                }
        }
        String 입력주소 = request.getParameter("주소");
        String num = request.getParameter("연번1");
        String sgg = request.getParameter("시군명");
        String period = request.getParameter("방치기간");
        String youngdo= request.getParameter("용도");
        String progress = request.getParameter("공정률");
        String gujork = request.getParameter("구조등급");
        String area = request.getParameter("연면적");
        DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry dbf = new DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry();
        dbf.dbfmodify(입력주소,num ,sgg, period, youngdo, progress, gujork, area);
        Filemove fm = new Filemove();
        fm.filemove();
%>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = "<%=ifcnt%>";
        if(a == "1"){
            alert("다시 시도해주세요 !");
            location.href = 'LTnb.html';
        } else {
            alert("저장 완료 !");
            location.href = 'LTnb.html';
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it is geotools library's problem, but I don't know how solve this problem. I use openlayers3, geoserver, geotools, java 1.7 version, jdk 1.7 and Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Without seeing `DbaseFileReaderTestMainEntry` it is hard to say why it doesn't compile - I can't see any evidence for this being a GeoTools problem.

Comment: Also you probably need to be using Java8 for any recent version of GeoTools